# What is the specific error to look for that guarantees wsfc initiated either restart or failover?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering

I am looking at **sql server error log** and the **cluster log (cluster.log)** file for each node in the cluster.

I can see couple of errors scattered around like `failed a periodic health check on file share`, `failing over group`, `because of 'Shutting down'`, `resource x is causing group y to failoer`...

What is specific error record to look for, that guarantees that the WSFC initiated either a restart or failover?

Comment: Isn't enough to look at SQL Server log and see that the instance was restarted? because either situation will cause it to log all those starting entries.

Comment: You are correct but then it may be restarted as part of general maintenance like patching, etc also.

Comment: Good point. What about joining the info I mentioned along with the logs indicated on Siva Dasari answer to your question? A maintenance patch would cause the restart, but not those cluster logs.

Comment: I agree but in the same time period I can see errors in the cluster logs, so I am looking for specific error log to help me analyze better

Answer (score 2):

You could use this command [Get-ClusterLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-clusterlog?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to generate cluster logs for each node,

Example command:

```
Get-ClusterLog -Node Node01, Node02, Node03 -Destination 'C:\Temp\' -UseLocalTime
```

The above command generates log files of each node at `C:\Temp` of each node.
Once you have the output, you could do following on those files to filer,

1. To filter only errors from the log file.

```
Select-String -Path C:\Temp\Node03_cluster.log -Pattern ' ERR '
```

2. To filter `failoverCount` messages.

```
Select-String -Path C:\Temp\Node03_cluster.log -Pattern  'failoverCount'
```

You would be able to mix and match the string filters to get appropriate information you are looking for.

Sample from one of our instances with filter (2) applied,

```
Line 40: ObjectId,ObjectName,resources,_acceptOwnershipCounts,_pOwnerNode,_state,_stateCounter,_markedBusyBy,_failoverInProgress,_failoverCount,_lastFailoverTime,_beingForcefullyDeleted,_operationFlags,_bounceBackFlags,_waitStart,_placementAttempts,_groupType,_numPreemptions,_numBlindPreemptions,_waitingForFirstPlacement,_priority,_defaultOwner,_flags,_persistentState,_failoverThreshold,_failoverPeriod,_autoFailbackType,_failbackWindowStart,_failbackWindowEnd,_description,_groupStartDelay,_lastOnlineOffline,antiAffinityClassNames,PreferredSite,_preferredOwners,_isCore,_lastOnlineNode,_groupStatusInformation,_moveTarget,_moveTargetBirthdate,_failoverTarget,_moveType,_isTargetedMove,_previousOwner,_queuedTarget,_hasIssuedMoveWithThisQueuedTarget,_targetedQueue,_savedLastOperationStatusCodeDuringQueue,_onlineTime,lastStateChangeTime,lastSeenMoveTime_GetSystemTime,lastSeenMoveTime_NodeId,_coldStartSetting,_placementOptions,providers
    Line 10958: [Verbose] 000012e0.000036bc::2022/05/02-07:34:14.124 INFO  [RCM] move of group AG01 from Node02(2) to Node03(3) of type MoveType::Failover is about to succeed, failoverCount=1, lastFailoverTime=2022/05/02-07:31:16.711 targeted=false
    Line 15455: [Verbose] 000012e0.00002b08::2022/05/02-07:34:23.178 DBG   [RCM] rcm::RcmGroup::UpdateAndGetFailoverCount=> (1, 2022/05/02-07:31:16.711)
    Line 15457: [Verbose] 000012e0.00002b08::2022/05/02-07:34:23.178 WARN  [RCM] Failing over group AG01, failoverCount 2, last time 2022/05/02-07:31:16.711.
    Line 16165: [Verbose] 000012e0.0000139c::2022/05/02-07:34:24.140 INFO  [RCM] move of group AG01 from Node03(3) to Node02(2) of type MoveType::Failover is about to succeed, failoverCount=2, lastFailoverTime=2022/05/02-07:34:23.170 targeted=false
    Line 16994: [Verbose] 000012e0.000036bc::2022/05/02-07:37:58.017 INFO  [RCM] move of group AG01 from Node02(2) to Node03(3) of type MoveType::Failover is about to succeed, failoverCount=3, lastFailoverTime=2022/05/02-07:35:00.680 targeted=false
    Line 19109: [Verbose] 000012e0.00002a1c::2022/05/02-07:38:01.398 DBG   [RCM] rcm::RcmGroup::UpdateAndGetFailoverCount=> (3, 2022/05/02-07:35:00.680)
    Line 19111: [Verbose] 000012e0.00002a1c::2022/05/02-07:38:01.398 WARN  [RCM] Failing over group AG01, failoverCount 4, last time 2022/05/02-07:35:00.680.
    Line 19608: [Verbose] 000012e0.00001c6c::2022/05/02-07:38:02.370 INFO  [RCM] move of group AG01 from Node03(3) to Node02(2) of type MoveType::Failover is about to succeed, failoverCount=4, lastFailoverTime=2022/05/02-07:38:01.385 targeted=false
    Line 29278: [Verbose] 000012e0.00001d68::2022/05/02-08:27:51.277 INFO  [RCM] move of group Available Storage from Node03(3) to w8mssql110agp0(1) of type MoveType::Drain is about to succeed, failoverCount=0, lastFailoverTime=1601/01/01-00:00:00.000 targeted=false
```

Hope this information helps.

Comment: Yes I have got these logs, but this question was to ask for the specific error message that guarantees me as an analyst to confirm that the failover or restart would have happened.

Comment: If you look at my filter options (1) and (2),  (2) will confirm the failover messages (check the sample that I have posted from one of our instances) and (1) will reveal all the errors that were happened.